# Fortran formatted write function triggers "has exited with code 408 (0x198)" on IF Composer 2013

Tags: debugging, fortran, fortran77, formatted

When following Fortran code is executed on the Intel Fortran Composer 2013 the compiler triggers a breakpoint at write function and retuns code 408:

```
       character*20  date_char
       character*10  LADATE

       ...
       if (date_char(3:3) .EQ. "") date_char(3:3)="0"
       if (date_char(7:7) .EQ. "") date_char(7:7)="0"
       write(LADATE,"(2A2,A4)")
     S date_char(3:4),date_char(7:8),date_char(9:12)
```

It is a fixed line-length format and the S represents the line continuation.

The date_char has a value of '  29  012013        ' and the LADATE '          '

As soon as the write statement is reached the debugger triggers a breakpoint and the Call Stack shows following system functions being called:

*for*_issue_diagnostics()
_for_emit_diagnostics()

Your time is appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. If you post a compilable snippet I'll cut and paste and try again. Until you do I suspect that an error occurs prior to the `write` statement and that the run-time mis-identifies the faulty line; this is a common occurrence.

Comment: Can you look up in your compiler documentation what code 408 is?

Comment: In your IF statements, is there supposed to be a space between the first set of double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the LADATE variable was actually a call-by-reference argument (FORTRAN77 default passing convention):

```
   SUBROUTINE MDATE(LADATE)

   character*20  date_char
   character*10  LADATE
   ...
   write(LADATE,"(2A2,A4)")
 S date_char(3:4),date_char(7:8),date_char(9:12)

   RETURN
   END
```

and it was passed as an argument several subroutines above as a just an 8-character string. Simply written, the call would be equivalent to:

```
   ...
   CHARACTER VAR*20
   ...
   CALL MDATE(VAR(10:17))
   ...
```

The program started, but after an attempt to access an inaccessible array addresses by the write function the breakpoint was triggered.